# How do I install a ceiling light where one never existed?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a hanging light fixture in a room that had no lights in the ceiling. There is a ceiling joist running down the center of the room. What is the best way to mount the fixture? Is there a finished piece that is big enough to cover the box if I mount it to the surface?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a pancake box mounted directly on the joist. (I'd suggest "fan rated" for future options.) This will end up flush with the drywall. Use 2" wood screws; not drywall screws to attach.

Alternately, if you didn't want it right on the joist, and you want to be absolutely sure your fixture isn't going to come crashing down at an awkward moment, get a retrofit ceiling box with a brace. They are really easy to install and might cost you an extra 10 bucks. This will also allow for a fan in the future if you want to go that way. Old work ceiling boxes that are rated for light fixtures do exist, but you're relying on the strength of the drywall and the accuracy of your install to hold them up.

Comment: Even if you mount the pancake box directly on the sheetrock so it is not flush (mount it to the joist!), the base of the light fixture will fit over it, so the light fixture will still sit flush against the ceiling.

Comment: +1 With the pancake, you may have to offset the box slightly so that its edge hangs over the side of the beam to allow room for the cable to enter the pancake. If the beam is a single 2 x something, this happens almost automatically. If it's doubled (2 - 2 x somethings), you will have to shift it slightly

Answer (score 0):

This would ultimately depend on what type of light as a lot of LED pendants will require the electronic parts to occupy the cubic space of the box.

For most pendant lights and chandeliers a regular pancake box will work.  For the heavier lights you should use a pancake box that is designed to support heavier weights.  They are usually marked as ceiling fan rated.

I would definitely recess the pancake box 1/2" by removing the sheetrock.  Not only does this insure a correct installation, but it also allows for more room in the canopy of the fixture where you can keep extra fixture wire. A lot of people will take their fixtures with them when they move and may have a higher ceiling.

[image]